# A question about counter examples or proof in real analysis

Tags: real-analysis

(a) Given an example of bounded sequence $\{a_n\}$ so that every subsequence 
$\{a_{n_k}\}_{k=1}^{\infty}$ is divergent or explain why no such sequence exists.

(b) Given an example of function $f:\mathbb{R}\to\mathbb{R}$ such that for every $a\in \mathbb{R}$ , $\lim_{x\to a} f(x)$ is does not exist or explain why no such function exists.

first by Bolzano -Weiertrass theorem every bounded sequence have convergent subsequence

for (b) is there exists such function

Comment: You can always find a function for which the limit doesn't exist at some point $a$. Do you want a function for which there is no limit existing at all points? Also, a is correct, as long as you are assuming that $a_n$ are real numbers (this is not mentioned by you, but it must be so, I expect).

Comment: @астонвіллаолофмэллбэрг..sorry i have edited now..can you check now please

Comment: The answer below contains such a function. Note that for every rational or irrational, there exists two sequences, of rationals only and irrationals only, which converge to that number. Therefore, the limit at a point would still be undefinable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For b), consider $f(x)=\chi_{\bf{Q}}(x)$. Suppose $\lim_{x\rightarrow a}\chi_{\bf{Q}}(x)=L$ exists for $a\in{\bf{R}}$, then find some $\delta>0$ such that if $0<|x-a|<\delta$, then $|\chi_{\bf{Q}}(x)-L|<1/2$. Now pick a rational number $\alpha$ and irrational number $\beta$ such that $0<|\alpha-a|<\delta$, and $0<|\beta-a|<\delta$, then $1=|\chi_{\bf{Q}}(\alpha)-\chi_{\bf{Q}}(\beta)|\leq|\chi_{\bf{Q}}(\alpha)-L|+|\chi_{\bf{Q}}(\beta)-L|<1/2+1/2=1$, a contradiction.

Comment: @user284331...i have edited now can you check

Comment: Yes I got what you meant, my example still goes through.

Comment: @user284331..is this work for every point

Comment: Okay I will edit and show you.

Comment: @user284331...thank you